# using Order By when string consist of numbers and letters to sort only by numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column were I need to sort by that contains Alphabetical characters and numbers

Now the following values

ABC223
ABC12

Now I need to sort this only by numbers ignoring the Alphabetical characters in the string,

Something to remember is sometimes the value can start with GD, othertimes with only A sometimes 123AB et

Is this at all possible?

Comment: If all your strings start with "ABC" it should do that already...

Comment: Forgot to mention, sometimes it can start with GD, othertimes with only A sometimes 123AB etc

Comment: @Roland Which language do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at: https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp and [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

If you use `udf` you can execute an ORDER BY with a regex replace.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(YourColumn, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you but I forgot to mention sometimes it can start with GD, othertimes with only A sometimes 123AB etc so SUBSTRING wont work in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`uasort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) to sort array of containing that values.

For example:

```
$pattern = "/\d+/";
$values = array('ABC123', 'ABC12', 'GD44'); //Just for example

uasort($values, function ($a, $b) use ($pattern)
   {
       $matches = array();
       preg_match($pattern, $a, $matches);
       $a = $matches[0];
       preg_match($pattern, $b, $matches);
       $b = $matches[0];

       return $a - $b;
   });

var_dump($values);
```

Also you can use `udf` for manipulating `regex` using sql query.